ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS After Enabling WordPress Multisite
I'm currently facing a challenge after enabling WordPress multisite on my installation. I can easily log in to the main dashboard at http://54.183.207.102/wp-admin, but I'm unable to access the subdirectory site at http://54.183.207.102/site1/wp-admin.
In the browser's network tab, I can see multiple requests being made to site1/wp-admin, but I consistently receive the following error:
This page isn’t working
54.183.207.102 redirected you too many times.
Try deleting your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
.htaccess File Configuration
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# Add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress`

wp-config.php File Configuration
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);

define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' );

define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', 'minor' );
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', '54.183.207.102' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', false);
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */


I've made several adjustments to the .htaccess file, but the issue persists. I would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance on how to resolve this redirect error. What could be causing the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS issue, and how can I fix it?

"The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are dynamically generated and should only be modified via WordPress filters." ??  And you did not read this, or .... ????

see any of: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wordpress+too+many+redirects
